# How I can use discord.py with PyNaCl problem?

Tags: discord.py

I´m having this problem:

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: RuntimeError: PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice

This is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands



client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Pronto!')

@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()

@client.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

client.run(TOKEN)
```

But I have PyNaCl installed what should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the **voice** version of discord.py
We do this by doing the following,

```py
pip install discord.py[voice]
```

This will install discord.py voice edition, which has all needed packages and how they should come :)